# Expand file names that have environment variables in their path

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, boost-filesystem

What's the best way to expand

```
${MyPath}/filename.txt to /home/user/filename.txt
```

or

```
%MyPath%/filename.txt to c:\Documents and settings\user\filename.txt
```

without traversing the path string looking for environment variables directly?

I see that wxWidgets has a [wxExpandEnvVars](http://www.gnu-darwin.org/www001/src/ports/x11-toolkits/py-wxPython26-common/work/wxPython-src-2.6.3.3/src/common/config.cpp) function.  I can't use wxWidgets in this case, so I was hoping to find a `boost::filesystem` equivalent or similar.

I am only using the home directory as an example, I am looking for general purpose path expansion.

Answer (score 33):

For UNIX (or at least POSIX) systems, have a look at [wordexp](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/wordexp.html):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <wordexp.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  wordexp_t p;
  char** w;
  wordexp( "$HOME/bin", &p, 0 );
  w = p.we_wordv;
  for (size_t i=0; i<p.we_wordc;i++ ) cout << w[i] << endl;
  wordfree( &p );
  return 0;
}
```

It seems it will even do glob-like expansions (which may or may not be useful for your particular situation).

Comment: For me, this is the other half way. This solution with the one above work on both Posix and Window.

Comment: I would upvote this three times if I could.  Great answer using the system-provided facilities which are certainly less prone to errors than regex stuff.

Comment: N.B.  this uses /bin/sh under the hood tho and forks processes to achieve the results.

Comment: Note that wordexp removed quotes, removes spaces e.t.c. Generally it works but your string will be seriously different after. For example having unmatched single quote is ok in filename but wordexp will remove it.

Comment: not only will it fork processes under the hood, it will also do cmdsubstitution. therefore this is open for injection attacks: `wordexp("$(sudo reboot)")`. there's a `WRDE_NOCMD` flag, but at least for me this will simply make `wordexp` segfault whenever i pass it a command for substitution (making this open for DoS attacks)

Answer (score 24):

On Windows, you can use [`ExpandEnvironmentStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724265.aspx). Not sure about a Unix equivalent yet.

Answer (score 24):

If you have the luxury of using C++11, then regular expressions are quite handy. I wrote a version for updating in place and a declarative version.

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>

// Update the input string.
void autoExpandEnvironmentVariables( std::string & text ) {
    static std::regex env( "\\$\\{([^}]+)\\}" );
    std::smatch match;
    while ( std::regex_search( text, match, env ) ) {
        const char * s = getenv( match[1].str().c_str() );
        const std::string var( s == NULL ? "" : s );
        text.replace( match[0].first, match[0].second, var );
    }
}

// Leave input alone and return new string.
std::string expandEnvironmentVariables( const std::string & input ) {
    std::string text = input;
    autoExpandEnvironmentVariables( text );
    return text;
}
```

An advantage of this approach is that it can be adapted easily to cope with syntactic variations and deal with wide strings too. (Compiled and tested using Clang on OS X with the flag -std=c++0x)

Comment: g++ 4.9.3 (Ubuntu) cannot compile, it's something related to conversion between iterator and const_iterator. I have to change  text.replace( match[0].first, match[0].second, var ); to text.replace( match.position(0), match.length(0), var );

Comment: Tried it with `gcc version 5.4.0 (Ubuntu)` with `g++ -std=c++11 -c -Wall expand.cpp` but didn't get any error.

Comment: If you could include the output (or send it to me) that would be great. I can't duplicate any errors on Ubuntu 18.04, sorry.

Comment: Does not work on gcc 4.8 and below because regex expressions are implemented on gcc 4.9 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530406/is-gcc-4-8-or-earlier-buggy-about-regular-expressions

Comment: See my answer for a modified version of this to support leaving missing vars alone for other parsers or processes to handle instead of removing, similar to `os.path.expandvars` in Python

Answer (score 7):

Simple and portable:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

static std::string expand_environment_variables( const std::string &s ) {
    if( s.find( "${" ) == std::string::npos ) return s;

    std::string pre  = s.substr( 0, s.find( "${" ) );
    std::string post = s.substr( s.find( "${" ) + 2 );

    if( post.find( '}' ) == std::string::npos ) return s;

    std::string variable = post.substr( 0, post.find( '}' ) );
    std::string value    = "";

    post = post.substr( post.find( '}' ) + 1 );

    const char *v = getenv( variable.c_str() );
    if( v != NULL ) value = std::string( v );

    return expand_environment_variables( pre + value + post );
}
```

`expand_environment_variables( "${HOME}/.myconfigfile" );` yields `/home/joe/.myconfigfile`

Comment: Note that this only expands a single environment variable. Which is OK for the example. If you need to expand multiple environment variables in one string, calls expane_environment_variables recursively on post.

Comment: Note: you call `getenv(variable.c_str())` twice for getting the same var, better to store result.

Comment: You're missing "char" after const* v

Answer (score 3):

As the question is tagged "wxWidgets", you can use `wxExpandEnvVars()` function used by [wxConfig](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_config_base.html) for its environment variable expansion. The function itself is unfortunately not documented but it basically does what you think it should and expands any occurrences of `$VAR`, `$(VAR)` or `${VAR}` on all platforms and also of `%VAR%` under Windows only.

Answer (score 2):

Within the C/C++ language, here is what I do to resolve environmental variables under Unix.  The fs_parm pointer would contain the filespec (or text) of possible environmental variables to be expanded.  The space that wrkSpc points to must be MAX_PATH+60 chars long.  The double quotes in the echo string are to prevent the wild cards from being processed.  Most default shells should be able to handle this.

```
   FILE *fp1;

   sprintf(wrkSpc, "echo \"%s\" 2>/dev/null", fs_parm);
   if ((fp1 = popen(wrkSpc, "r")) == NULL || /* do echo cmd     */
       fgets(wrkSpc, MAX_NAME, fp1) == NULL)/* Get echo results */
   {                        /* open/get pipe failed             */
     pclose(fp1);           /* close pipe                       */
     return (P_ERROR);      /* pipe function failed             */
   }
   pclose(fp1);             /* close pipe                       */
   wrkSpc[strlen(wrkSpc)-1] = '\0';/* remove newline            */
```

For MS Windows, use the ExpandEnvironmentStrings() function.

Comment: like the `wordexp` solution, this is wide open for injection attacks: `fs_parm = "$(sudo reboot)";`. not only is it open to command substitution, it's also a text-book "quotation injection": `fs_parm ="foo\"; sudo reboot\"".

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use:

```
const unsigned short expandEnvVars(std::string& original)
{
    const boost::regex envscan("%([0-9A-Za-z\\/]*)%");
    const boost::sregex_iterator end;
    typedef std::list<std::tuple<const std::string,const std::string>> t2StrLst;
    t2StrLst replacements;
    for (boost::sregex_iterator rit(original.begin(), original.end(), envscan); rit != end; ++rit)
        replacements.push_back(std::make_pair((*rit)[0],(*rit)[1]));
    unsigned short cnt = 0;
    for (t2StrLst::const_iterator lit = replacements.begin(); lit != replacements.end(); ++lit)
    {
        const char* expanded = std::getenv(std::get<1>(*lit).c_str());
        if (expanded == NULL)
            continue;
        boost::replace_all(original, std::get<0>(*lit), expanded);
        cnt++;
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Qt, this works for me:

```cpp
#include <QString>
#include <QRegExp>

QString expand_environment_variables( QString s )
{
    QString r(s);
    QRegExp env_var("\\$([A-Za-z0-9_]+)");
    int i;

    while((i = env_var.indexIn(r)) != -1) {
        QByteArray value(qgetenv(env_var.cap(1).toLatin1().data()));
        if(value.size() > 0) {
            r.remove(i, env_var.matchedLength());
            r.insert(i, value);
        } else
            break;
    }
    return r;
}
```

```
expand_environment_variables(QString("$HOME/.myconfigfile"));
```

yields

```
/home/martin/.myconfigfile
```

(It also works with nested expansions)

Answer (score 0):

I needed the ability to parse nested env variables while leaving untouched those not found in the environment for another parser to handle so I came up with this based on @sfkleach's excellent answer:

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>

// Update the input string.
void autoExpandEnvironmentVariables(std::string& text) {
    using namespace std;
    static regex envRegex("\\$(\\w+|\\{\\w+\\})", regex::ECMAScript);

    // 0,1 indicates to get the full match + first subgroup
    size_t offset = 0;
    const string matchText = text;
    sregex_token_iterator matchIter(matchText.begin(), matchText.end(), envRegex, {0, 1});
    for (sregex_token_iterator end; matchIter != end; ++matchIter) {
        const string match = matchIter->str();
        string envVarName = (++matchIter)->str();
        
        // Remove matching braces
        if (envVarName.front() == '{' && envVarName.back() == '}') {
            envVarName.erase(envVarName.begin());
            envVarName.erase(envVarName.end()-1);
        }
        
        // Search for env var and replace if found
        const char * s = getenv(envVarName.c_str());
        if (s != nullptr) {
            string value(s);

            // Handle nested env vars
            autoExpandEnvironmentVariables(value);
            
            // Since we're manipulating the string, do a new find
            // instead of using original match info
            size_t pos = text.find(match, offset);
            if (pos != string::npos) {
                text.replace(pos, match.length(), value);
                offset = pos + value.length();
            }
        } else {
            offset += match.length();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some very nice features in this answer compared with my answer. I like the separate handling of the nested environment variables and the better regex used for finding matches. Using matchIter is very attractive but I am slightly concerned about whether or not it robustly makes progress when updating "${foo}${bar}" and $foo expands to an empty string (non-null). The iterator finds matches based on indexes so it presumably bumps the index in order to ensure it doesn't find the same match, which might cause it to skip `${bar}`.

Comment: string (non-null). 

UPDATE: Tested using g++ 11.3.0 (Cygwin) and unfortunately I found quite a few issues. In particular even substituting non-empty short values seemed to confuse the iterator causing it to skip.

Comment: @sfkleach Thanks for the feedback, I created test cases for longer vars, but didn't consider short or empty ones. Mutating the string while iterating was a bad idea so I've updated it to match on a static copy. Let me know if you find any other issues.

Answer (score 0):

Since in certain use cases `std::regex` could be a little heavy, I'll share another idea for a possible portable way to do it ([godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/v9v6M9jfM))

```cpp
#include <string_view>
#include <string>
#include <optional>
#include <cctype> // std::isalnum()
#include <cstdlib> // std::getenv, ::getenv_s()


//:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
namespace sys //:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
{

namespace details
   {
    using var_value_t = std::optional<std::string>;
    using f_resolve_var_t = var_value_t (*)(const std::string_view);
   }


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
[[nodiscard]] details::var_value_t resolve_var_getenv(const std::string_view var_name)
{
    // Unfortunately getenv API requires a null terminated string,
    // so I have to instantiate a std::string
    const std::string var_name_str = std::string(var_name);

  #if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
    // std::getenv deemed unsafe, the Microsoft safe version requires a copy
    // Check if variable is present
    std::size_t val_size_plus_null = 0;
    if( 0==::getenv_s(&val_size_plus_null, nullptr, 0, var_name_str.c_str()) and val_size_plus_null>0 )
       {
        std::string var_value;
        var_value.resize(val_size_plus_null-1);
        if( 0==::getenv_s(&val_size_plus_null, var_value.data(), val_size_plus_null, var_name_str.c_str()) )
           {
            return { std::move(var_value) };
           }
       }
  #else
    if( const char* const val_cstr = std::getenv(var_name_str.c_str()) )
       {
        return { std::string(val_cstr) };
       }
  #endif

    return {};
}


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
template<details::f_resolve_var_t resolve_var =resolve_var_getenv>
[[nodiscard]] std::string expand_env_vars(const std::string_view input)
{
    std::string output;
    output.reserve( 2 * input.size() ); // An arbitrary guess

    class parser_t final
    {
     private:
        const std::string_view input;
        std::size_t i = 0;
        std::size_t i_chunkstart = 0;
        std::size_t i_chunkend = 0;
        std::size_t i_varstart = 0;
        std::size_t i_varend = 0;

     public:
        parser_t(const std::string_view sv) noexcept
          : input(sv)
           {}

        [[nodiscard]] bool got_var_name() noexcept
           {
            while( true )
               {
                if( got('%') )
                   {// Possible %var_name%
                    i_chunkend = pos();
                    next();
                    if( got_varname_token() and got('%') )
                       {
                        next();
                        return true;
                       }
                   }
                else if( got('$') )
                   {
                    i_chunkend = pos();
                    next();
                    if( got('{') )
                       {// Possible ${var_name}
                        next();
                        if( got_varname_token() and got('}') )
                           {
                            next();
                            return true;
                           }
                       }
                    else if( got_varname_token() )
                       {// Possible $var_name
                        return true;
                       }
                   }
                else if( !next() )
                   {
                    break;
                   }
               }
            return false;
           }

        [[nodiscard]] std::string_view chunk_before() const noexcept { return input.substr(i_chunkstart, i_chunkend-i_chunkstart); }
        [[nodiscard]] std::string_view var_name() const noexcept { return input.substr(i_varstart, i_varend-i_varstart); }
        [[nodiscard]] std::string_view remaining_chunk() const noexcept { return input.substr(i_chunkstart); }
        void var_was_substituted() noexcept { i_chunkstart = pos(); }

    private:
        [[nodiscard]] std::size_t pos() const noexcept { return i; }
        [[nodiscard]] bool got(const char ch) const noexcept { return i<input.size() and input[i]==ch; }
        [[maybe_unused]] bool next() noexcept { return ++i<input.size(); }

        [[nodiscard]] bool got_varname_initial_char() const noexcept { return i<input.size() and std::isalnum(input[i]); }
        [[nodiscard]] bool got_varname_char() const noexcept { return i<input.size() and (std::isalnum(input[i]) or input[i]=='_'); }
        [[nodiscard]] bool got_varname_token() noexcept
           {
            i_varstart = pos();
            if( got_varname_initial_char() )
               {
                next();
                while( got_varname_char() ) next();
               }
            i_varend = pos();
            return i_varend>i_varstart;
           }
    } parser(input);

    while( parser.got_var_name() )
       {
        if( const auto val = resolve_var(parser.var_name()) )
           {
            output += parser.chunk_before();
            output += val.value();
            parser.var_was_substituted();
           }
       }
    output += parser.remaining_chunk();

    return output;
}

}//::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



#define TEST_UNITS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#ifdef TEST_UNITS ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <map>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
[[nodiscard]] sys::details::var_value_t resolve_var_test(const std::string_view var_name)
{
    static const std::map<std::string,std::string,std::less<void>> m =
       {
        {"foo", "FOO"},
        {"bar", "BAR"}
       };

    if( const auto it = m.find(var_name); it!=m.end() )
       {
        return { it->second };
       }
    return {};
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#define BOOST_UT_DISABLE_MODULE
#include <https://raw.githubusercontent.com/boost-experimental/ut/master/include/boost/ut.hpp>
namespace ut = boost::ut;
static ut::suite<"sys::expand_env_vars()"> sys_expand_env_vars_tests = []
{////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    using namespace std::literals; // "..."sv
    using ut::expect;
    using ut::that;

    ut::test("no expansions") = []
       {
        expect( that % sys::expand_env_vars<resolve_var_test>(""sv)==""sv );
        expect( that % sys::expand_env_vars<resolve_var_test>("foo"sv)=="foo"sv );
       };

    ut::test("single expansions") = []
       {
        expect( that % sys::expand_env_vars<resolve_var_test>("%foo%"sv)=="FOO"sv );
        expect( that % sys::expand_env_vars<resolve_var_test>("$foo"sv)=="FOO"sv );
        expect( that % sys::expand_env_vars<resolve_var_test>("${foo}"sv)=="FOO"sv );
       };

    ut::test("multiple expansions") = []
       {
        expect( that % sys::expand_env_vars<resolve_var_test>("/%foo%/%bad%/%foo/fo%o/%foo%%bar%/%foo%%bad%/%foo%"sv)=="/FOO/%bad%/%foo/fo%o/FOOBAR/FOO%bad%/FOO"sv );
        expect( that % sys::expand_env_vars<resolve_var_test>("/$foo/$bad/$fooo/fo$o/$foo$bar/$foo$bad/$foo"sv)=="/FOO/$bad/$fooo/fo$o/FOOBAR/FOO$bad/FOO"sv );
        expect( that % sys::expand_env_vars<resolve_var_test>("/${foo}/${bad}/${foo/fo${o/${foo}${bar}/${foo}${bad}/${foo}"sv)=="/FOO/${bad}/${foo/fo${o/FOOBAR/FOO${bad}/FOO"sv );
 
        expect( that % sys::expand_env_vars<resolve_var_test>("%foo%/foo/$bar/bar"sv)=="FOO/foo/BAR/bar"sv );
        expect( that % sys::expand_env_vars<resolve_var_test>("%bad%/bar/$bad/bar/${bar} /"sv)=="%bad%/bar/$bad/bar/BAR /"sv );
        expect( that % sys::expand_env_vars<resolve_var_test>("fo%o/%foo%/ba$r/bar%bar%$bar${bar}bar"sv)=="fo%o/FOO/ba$r/barBARBARBARbar"sv );
       };

};///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif // TEST_UNITS ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


int main()
{
}
```