# Is there an equivalent to Python's expandvars in C?

Tags: c, linux, environment-variables

I have a string stored in a file that is read into a string.
I wish to replace variables defined in *nix shell format with the corresponding environment values.

For example, an environment variable of `$DEPLOY=/home/user` will turn `"deploypath=$DEPLOY/dir1"` into `"deploypath=/home/user/dir1"`

Is there a simple library to do this?

i.e.

```
#include "supersimplelib.h"
char *newstr = expandvars(oldstr);
```

(or similar)

I understand I could use a regular expression lib and then call `getenv()` but I was wondering if there was another simpler way?

It will only be compiled under Linux.

Comment: Can or should I answer my own question?
I have found this [wordexp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/wordexp.html)
and it is what I was after.

Comment: Yes, you can (and should).  See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: I cant for another 7 hours :) so ill use this comment to placehold my answer:

I found this and it is what I am after
[wordexp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/wordexp.html)

I also found a related question which also has the same answer.
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902681/expand-file-names-that-have-environment-variables-in-their-path)

Comment: Was writing my answer while you were posting this...

Comment: FWIW, Windows has the [`ExpandEnvironmentStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724265%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function for doing just this, but it's not portable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

wordexp appears to do what you need.  Here's a modified version of an example program from [this manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/wordexp) (which also gives a lot of excellent detail on wordexp).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wordexp.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        wordexp_t p;
        char **w;
        int i;
        wordexp("This is my path: $PATH", &p, 0);
        w = p.we_wordv;
        for (i=0; i<p.we_wordc; i++)
                printf("%s ", w[i]);
        printf("\n");
        wordfree(&p);
        return 0;
}
```

This produces the following output on my machine (Ubuntu Linux 10.04, used gcc to compile).

```
$ ./a.out 
This is my path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

I found the manpage above to be most useful, but there's also more information from the [GNU C Library Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Word-Expansion.html#Word-Expansion).