# How to expand path containing environment variable in C++

Tags: c++, linux, boost, stl

Is there a way to expand environment variables in a path? For example:

```
std::string myPath = expandEnv("$SOME_VAR/dir/")
```

So that when myPath is printed it contains the absolute path that would result from expanding $SOME_VAR ?
I remember seeing this done somewhere, or might have implemented it myself, but I can't remember where.

I know Windows have it, is there anything in C++ STL, Boost or Linux headers that does that?

Comment: ["Simple and portable" - as noted by the user.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20715800/4766989)

First result on google...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112494/how-to-expand-environment-variables-in-ini-files-using-boost/17128601?s=13|0.0000#17128601

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/cR5oM5/2) and then expanded the matches