# How to use sscanf to parse an program argument in C

Tags: c, scanf

I've been looking every `sscanf` post here and I can't find an exact solution suitable for my problem. I was implementing my own Shell and one of the characteristics is that if I find the dollar sign `$`, I got to replace what is exactly behind with the environmental variable:

`cd $HOME` should actually be replaced by `cd /home/user` before I even execute the cd.

My question is what is the code to use `sscanf` to take out the dollar sign and simply get HOME on the same string? I've been struggling with some null pointers trying this:

```
char * change;
if (strcmp(argv[1][0],'$')==0){
                    
   change = malloc(strlen(argv[y]));
   sscanf(argv2[y]+1,"%[_a-zA-Z0-9]",change);
   argv2[y]=getenv(change);
}
```

But this seems to be failing, I'm having a segmentation fault core. (If needed i put more code, my question is specially focused on the sscanf).
Quick explanation `argv` is an array of pointers to the lines entered and parsed, so actually the content of `argv[0] = "cd"` and `argv[1]="$HOME"`. I also know that the variable I'm going to receive after the `$` has the format `%[_a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Please ignore the non failure treatment.

Comment: Put only the amount of code needed to reproduce the problem, but make sure that it can compile.

Comment: this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902681/expand-file-names-that-have-environment-variables-in-their-path

Comment: `strcmp(argv[1][0],'$')` compares *character strings* not individual *characters*. Invoking a function that requires a *nul-terminated* string without providing a *nul-terminated* string results in *Undefined Behavior*.

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica and so can I use ````==```` operator with characters?

Comment: Yes, just `if (argv[1][0] == '$')`

Comment: ¡Perfect! Thank you very much. For further questioning, is malloc really needed here?

Comment: No, not really. So long as you know what your longest argument will be, you can just use an array with *automatic storage duration*. `char change[1024];` should be fine. (you have at least a Megabyte of stack space, using 1% for a fixed buffer is fine) The general rule is simply *Don't Skimp on Buffer Size!*. So if your longest argument is 40-chars, a buffer of 128-chars is fine. A buffer size of 1-4K is fairly common (except on embedded microcontrollers where storage is at a premium)

Comment: You also have your indexes a bit confused (unless your program is named `cd`). `argv[0]` is always the *Program Name with absolute path*. `argv[1]` is your first *command-line argument*, `argv[2]` the second, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked "is `malloc()` necessary" in  your code snipped and the answer was "no", you could use a simple array. In reality, if you are simply making use of the return of `getenv()` without modification in the same scope without any other calls to `getenv()`, all you need is a pointer. `getenv()` will return a pointer to the `value` part of the `name=value` pair within the program environment. However the pointer may be a pointer to a statically allocated array, so any other calls to `getenv()` before you make use of the pointer can cause the text to change. Also, do not modify the string returned by `getenv()` or you will be modifying the environment of the process.

That said, for your simple case, you could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char *envp = NULL,      /* pointer for return of getenv() */
        buf[MAXC];          /* buffer to parse argv[2] w/sscanf */

    if (argc < 3) { /* validate at least 2 program arguments given */
        printf ("usage: %s cmd path\n", strrchr (argv[0], '/') + 1);
        return 1;
    }

    if (*argv[2] == '$')    /* chest 1st char of argv[2] == '$' */
        if (sscanf (argv[2] + 1, "%1023[_a-zA-Z0-9]", buf) != 1) {
            fputs ("error: invalid format following '$'.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }

    if (!(envp = getenv (buf))) {   /* get environment var from name in buf */
        fprintf (stderr, "'%s' not found in environment.\n", buf);
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("%s %s\n", argv[1], envp);  /* output resulting command line */
}
```

Right now the program just outputs what the resulting command line would be after retrieving the environment variable. You can adjust and build the array of pointers for `execv` as needed.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/getenvhome "cd" '$HOME'
cd /home/david
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: I feel bad for the -1, because it's very understandable, but you missed the question being asked. The `argv` in their question is **not** what they will be receiving in their `main`, it is the `argv` that you pass to something like the `execve` system call.

Comment: You actually answer what they care about later in the answer, so it would be a +1 from me were it not for the above misunderstanding and the couple leading paragraphs that resulted from it before getting to the answer.

Comment: To be clear I was the -1, and have now switched it to a +1.

Comment: No worries. I generally take the approach on situations like this to drop a comment and say "Hey dummy, you misread the question...". It's just an approach I take of "being helpful" rather than "being critical" when what happened was a clear misunderstanding. Thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: ¡That was very helpful! I changed to ````sscanf (argv[2] + 1, "%1023[_a-zA-Z0-9]", buf)```` and seems working nice. I have one more question, my intent is to enter back the value of ````buf```` into ````argv2```` because as someone pointed out is not the same as the ````argv```` passed to the main function, it is actually a structure that was given to us by the proffessor with the variables received from parsing the lines entered in our own minishell:

Quick explanation argv is an array of pointers to the lines entered and parsed, so actually the content of argv[0] = "cd" and argv[1]="$HOME"

Comment: Yes, that was pointed out. No worries. The words "my shell" hinted at it. But this is also a good real-world example of why having two different variables named `argv` may lead to confusion as `argv` is the second parameter to `main`defined by the C-standard. Good luck with your coding.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `sscanf` here, you can just slide the pointer.

If `argv[1]` points to the string `"$HOME"`, then `argv[1] + 1` points to `"HOME"`, so your example code would just become:

```c
char * change;
if (argv[y][0] == '$')
{
    change = argv[y] + 1;
}
```

(But in this case your variable should not be named `change`. Call your variables *what they represent*, for example in this case `variable_name`, because it contains the name of the shell variable you will be expanding - remember your code is for **communicating to other humans** your intent and other helpful information about the code.)

To be clear, whether you do `sscanf` or this trick, you still have to do error checking to make sure the variable name is actually the right characters.

Remember that `sscanf` won't tell you if there are wrong characters, it'll just stop - if the user writes a variable like `$FO)O` (because they made a typo while trying to type `$FOO`) `sscanf` will just scan out the first valid characters and ignore the invalid ones, and return `FO` instead.

In this case ignoring bad data at the end would be bad because user interfaces (that includes shells) should minimize the chances that a user mistake silently does an unintended wrong thing.

Comment: Good approach here. The only justification for `sscanf (...` would be if the argument could contain characters other than what is included in the character class. If that's not a possibility, then your approach is all that is needed. I agree with the naming comment as well. As you show above, you could simply use `getenv (argv[y] + 1);` and save the additional pointer.

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica Doesn't `sscanf` just stop parsing upon the first wrong character instead of indicating an error? So I think either approach requires error handling. (See edit.)

Comment: Yes. On the first mismatch between a *conversion specifier* and the input a *matching-failure* occurs and character extraction from the buffer ceases. You are correct. Validation is required  See [Henry Spencer's 10 Commandments for C Programmers - No. 6](http://www.seebs.net/c/10com.html) ... *We be warned...*